# Co-author in conference presentation

Tags: conference

EDIT: I asked the question poorly, so what follows is an edit of the original.

When submitting an abstract for a presentation on research that is based on joint-work, should all authors be listed or only the presenter(s)?

Answer (score 4):

Co-authorship has (almost) nothing to do with conference registration.

Normally, each person who wants to go to the conference has to register for the conference or else, you know, the conference won't let them in. Just like each person who goes to see a movie has to buy a ticket.

And if you're going to present a paper at a conference, then you need to be at the conference, thus you need to "buy your ticket" and register.  If you co-authors want to be at the conference, they have to register too, whether or not their names happen to be on the paper, and if they don't want to go to the conference they don't have to register.

The only way that co-authorship ever connects to conference registration is for certain conferences that require you to pay for at least one registration per N papers (e.g., if N=2 and you're going to present three papers, then one of your co-authors has to buy a registration even if you're the only one going).  I find that obnoxious, but that's the economic model these conferences have chosen.

Comment: That's interesting. Do you mind providing any example of such a conference? I am just curious.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Here is an example: [IEEE Conference on Decision and Control](https://cdc2020.ieeecss.org/registration.php). If you look at the registration costs, you may note the right-most column says "# paper uploads", where regular registrations support 3 papers and student registrations support only 1 paper.

Comment: It might be a money-grab, but it might also be a way to encourage new researcher attendance. Otherwise you could have one PI presenting 20 papers with none of the PhD/postdocs present to save on budgets. That is a problem both for new researchers (who already depend a lot on the goodwill of their feudal lord, I mean PI, to start their career) and for the conference audience (because it is hard to answer questions on a topic you spent less than a full-time week on in the last year).

Comment: @jakebeal Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 1):

Most conferences require the attendance of at least one of the authors. Others may also register, but usually there is a cost involved. I don't know of any that require all authors to attend. I think it would be unlikely.

So, one is normally sufficient.

It might be useful for more than one to attend, so that the one(s) not presenting can faithfully capture any questions asked, so as not to lose those ideas.