# Which authors should be listed in a conference presentation?

Tags: conference, authorship, presentation

I asked a poorly-worded question [previously](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/154842/co-author-in-conference-presentation), so I'll try again.

Suppose someone is submitting an abstract for a talk that is based on joint work with other researchers. Further suppose that the other co-authors will not be presenting (or even attending the conference). As a matter of *attribution*, should all authors be listed on the talk?

Answer (score 3):

The practice that I have typically seen is to list all authors, but highlight/bold/underline the name of the speaker.  That way, credit is given both for speaking and for production of the material being spoken about.